# PHP - Why is a concatenated print_r printed out of order?

Tags: php

Why is it that

```
echo "Value of FILES['upload'] ";
print_r($_FILES['upload']);
```

prints `Value of FILES['upload'] Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 )`

whereas

```
echo "Value of FILES['upload'] ".print_r($_FILES['upload'])."<br/>";
```

prints `Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) Value of FILES['upload'] 1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `print_r()` function does not **return** the string by default. You have to tell it too. When you call it, it automatically writes its output to the output buffer. Since your echo statement is still in the process of being concatenated, it hasn't been echoed yet. So your array gets printed first and then the echo line gets printed after it's finished concatenating.

To make `print_r()` return its output rather than sending it immediately, specify its second parameter:

```
echo "Value of FILES['upload'] ".print_r($_FILES['upload'], true)."<br/>";
```

Answer (score 10):

`print_r` by default does the printing - it doesn't return the string.

So, that "1" you're getting in your second output was the return value of `print_r`.

You want `print_r($_FILES['upload'], TRUE)` to make it return the string for inclusion in your concatenation.

See [the PHP manual page on print_r](http://php.net/print_r).

Answer (score 3):

php.net/print_r

Thats because print_r prints your value on screen, and when you put it in echo, your echo also prints out it's return value

Answer (score 2):

print_r directly outputs its data to your screen. Try adding the second parameter to print_r for example:

```
echo " Hello world: " . print_r($my_array, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, [**`print_r()`**](http://fr.php.net/print_r) does print the content of the variable ; not return it.

If you want that content returned as a string, you have to pass `true` as a second parameter, when calling `print_r()` :

```
echo "blah : " . print_r($myVariable, true);
```

If you call this :

```
echo "Value of FILES['upload'] ";
print_r($_FILES['upload']);
```

Then, the first line does an `echo`, which displays a string, and, then, the second line displays the content of the variable.

On the other hand, if you do this :

```
echo "Value of FILES['upload'] ".print_r($_FILES['upload'])."<br/>";
```

Then, the `print_r()` function is called, and displays the content of the variable, and, then, the return-value of `print_r()` is concatenated to the other strings, and displayed.