# PHP, values in 2d array is always 1

Tags: php, arrays, firebug, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - Why is a concatenated print_r printed out of order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243584/php-why-is-a-concatenated-print-r-printed-out-of-order)

the following is a piece of code which has $input in the format of `S:2:0;M:7:9;L:4:9;XL:6:0;XXL:6:9` these are parsed and stored into the 2d array .. by the following code

```
    $stock_data = explode(';', $input);
    foreach($stock_data as $value) {
        $value = explode(':', $value);

        if (!empty($value[0])) {

            $temp_size = $value[0];
            $stock[$value[0]] = array('winkel' => $value[1], 'distributeur' => $value[2]);

            fb('afetr array val = '.$temp_size.' = its val -|'. print_r($stock[$temp_size]['distributeur']).'|',FirePHP::INFO);
        }
    }

    return $stock;
```

the values in the `print_r($stock[$temp_size]['distributeur']` or `print_r($stock[$temp_size]['winkel']` is always 1, even if later i try to print_r the whole array `$stock`, all it has got is 1.

I was trying for `print_r()` to show the array as it should be, What is going wrong here.

Comment: to see what your function returns try `var_dump(getAllStock("yourproductid"));` That "1" is printed by the line with fb().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because [that's what `print_r` returns](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). If you want it to return the string, add the 2nd parameter:

```
print_r($stock[$temp_size]['distributeur'], true)
```